# Compiling PHP 5.1.6 with PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, pdo, compilation

I originally [asked this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/43531/compiling-php-5-1-6-with-pdo-mysql) and haven't got any response and I figure it's programming related so, here goes...

---

A while ago a large client of ours moved to a single hosting provider who spec'd out a software environment which would be consistent accross all the live servers.

Amongs other things this includes Apache 2.2.8 and PHP 5.1.6.

We had an ubuntu 8.04 server for development and these versions of Apache and PHP are not the default installed. So I had to compile them from source. These versions have happily been running for over a year now.

We're starting a new site build and we want to use ZendFrameword which requires PDO_MySQL.

I've tried recompiling with the following... (underscore shows continuation of line)

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs _
--with-config-file-path=/user/local/apache2/conf/php.ini _
--with-curl=/usr/lib/ --with-mysql=shared --with-mysqli=shared _
--with-zlib --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/ _
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/ --enable-soap --enable-pdo=shared _
--with-pdo-mysql=shared --with-sqlite=shared
...
make
...
make install
...
libtool --finish /sources/php-5.1.6/libs
```

Which all works fine, and when I bring apache back up, it shows me the new ./configure in the phpinfo().

After doing this MySQL stops working, the MYSQL section disappears and msyql stops working.

The make, make install, libtool... puts the *.so files in

/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20050922

The configure I have used previously which enabled MySQL but not PDO is

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs _
--with-config-file-path=/user/local/apache2/conf/php.ini _
--with-curl=/usr/lib/ --with-mysql --with-mysqli _
--with-zlib --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/ _
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/ --enable-soap
```

I'm not a massive *nix person, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: 5.2.10/5.3.0 are current stable releases.  Are you sure you want 3-year-old version which might have known security vulnerabilities?

Comment: @porneL A while ago a large client of ours moved to a single hosting provider who spec'd out a software environment which would be consistent accross all the live servers.

Comment: @porneL We're in a situation where we have to use what we are given. The client is quite massive (hundreds of brands globally) and so a migration to a different version is a mamoth task. "if it aint broke, don't fix it" and all that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it will really help, but what if you remove every instance of "`=shared`" in your configure line ?

For example, here is an configure command I've used some time ago *(as given by *phpinfo*)* :

```
$ /usr/local/php-5.1.6/bin/php -i | grep 'configure'
Configure Command =>  './configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.1.6' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php-5.1.6' 
  '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2' '--disable-ipv6' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--enable-bcmath' 
  '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--with-ttf' 
  '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-ldap' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mcrypt' 
  '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-sqlite' 
  '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--with-xmlrpc' 
  '--with-xsl' '--with-pear'
```

(newlines added for the sake of readability)

Does it help ?

Comment: That worked. Should really of thought of that one myself. I'd be interested to see a working compilation with the shared modules though. Just as a learning exercise

Comment: OK, nice to know where the problem was coming ; actually, "shared" kinda jumped into my eyes, as I have **never** used it ^^

Comment: If that fixed your problem... could it be that you just forgot to load the modules that where compiled into shared objects via extension=php\_pdo\_mysql.so in your php.ini (or another config file)?

Answer (score -1):

No need to recompile whole PHP. Just compile PDO_MYSQL module alone. Use `pecl` to install it:

```
pecl install PDO_MYSQL
```

For that you will need `phpize` installed. On Debian machines it is provided by package called `php5-dev`. Afterwards just add it to your `php.ini` and restart Apache.

If you are on Debian/Ubuntu system PDO_MYSQL is provided in package called `php5-mysql`

Comment: From my post "We had an ubuntu 8.04 server for development and these versions of Apache and PHP are not the default installed. So I had to compile them from source."